# How can I get data from two ForeignKey fields in TastyPie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have two models.

```
class Eatery(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'eatery'

    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    approve_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=True, default = None, related_name="Establishment author")

    class Comments(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'comments'

        eatery = models.ForeignKey(Eatery, null=False)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        approve_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
```

My TastyPie models:

```
class EateryCommentsResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'author', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comments.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comments_eatery'
        filtering = {
            'author': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
        include_resource_uri = False
        #always_return_data = True
        paginator_class = Paginator

class EateryResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'author', full=True)
    comments = fields.ForeignKey(EateryCommentsResource, 'comments', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Eatery.objects.all()
        #excludes = ['description']
        resource_name = 'eatery'
        filtering = {
            'author': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'comments': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
        fields = ['user', 'comments']
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        include_resource_uri = False
        always_return_data = True
        paginator_class = Paginator
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

I can't getting EateryResource with comments. When I getting without comments, It works. How can I get EateryResourse with UserResource and CommentsResource.
Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the comments are linked to your eatery throug a ForeignKey, you need to define your `EateryResource` like this:

```
class EateryResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'author', full=True)
    comments = fields.ToManyField(EateryCommentsResource, 'comment_set', full=True)
```

Comment: But I defined like this:
comments = fields.ForeignKey(EateryCommentsResource, 'comments', full=True)

Comment: Yes in your resource, which is wrong. Because in your model it is defined that an Eatery can have many comments (since comment has a ForeignKey to Eatery). If you were on the plain django scope you would get all your comments for an Eatery through `eatery.comment_set.all()` (returning a list of comments) right? So you need to reflect this on your resource as-well...